# How to reposition a file by having a track on bytes which were decoded to corresponding characters?

Tags: java, nio, file-access

Question may be quite vague, let me expound it here. 
I'm developing an application in which I'll be reading data from a file. I've a FileReader class which opens the file in following fashion

```
currentFileStream = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
fileChannel = currentFileStream.getChannel();
```

data is read as following

```
bytesRead = fileChannel.read(buffer);  // Data is buffered using a ByteBuffer
```

I'm processing the data in any one of the 2 forms, one is binary and other is character. 
If its processed as character I do an additional step of decoding this ByteBuffer into CharBuffer

```
CoderResult result = decoder.decode(byteBuffer, charBuffer, false);
```

Now my problem is I need to read by repositioning the file from some offset during recovery mode in case of some failure or crash in application.

For this, I maintain a byteOffset which keeps track of no of bytes processed during binary mode and I persist this variable.

If something happens I reposition the file like this

```
fileChannel.position(byteOffset);
```

which is pretty straightforward.

But if processing mode is character, I maintain recordOffset which keeps track of character position/offset in the file. During recovery I make calls to read() internally till I get some character offset which is persisted recordOffset+1.

Is there anyway to get corresponding bytes which were needed to decode characters? For instance I want something similar like this if recordOffset is 400 and its corresponding byteOffset is 410 or 480 something( considering different charsets). So that while repositioning I can do this

```
fileChannel.position(recordOffset); //recordOffset equivalent value in number of bytes
```

instead of making repeated calls internally in my application.
Other approach I could think for this was using an InputStreamReader's skip method.

If there are any better approach for this or if possible to get byte - character mapping, please let me know.

Comment: Are you reading both the characters and binary form data from the same file i.e. Single file which contains some binary data followed by some encrypted characters and followed again some binary data

Comment: No mode is either exclusively binary or character, not simultaneously.

Comment: are you using base64 encoding/decoding technique? How you are able to store half decoded output to output file? How you are storing the file in encoded form, do you read some characters/bytes of fixed length lets says 1024 bytes then encode it and then store it.... this all info will be needed to formulate formula that can map actually decoded char to recordOffsetBytes of input file

Comment: 1) I'm not storing half decoded output to any file
2) I read blocks(in bytes) of fixed size from file, then pass that to decoder